# firefox absolute div inside relative div error

Tags: html, css, firefox, position

```
<div class="menu-item" >    //top container
       <a href="banks.html" class="menu-item-image">    //link when image or slide div clicked
            <img src="images/banking.png" alt="banking"/>   //relative image
            <div class="slide" style="background:#666666;">Find Banks</div>  //this div should slide
       </a> 
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kpppvjmq/1/

i place an absolute div inside of relative. i want absolute to slide over the relative div on hover. it worked in chrome. but not in Firefox and IE. absolute div came out of outer div. i need cross browser solution.

Answer (score 0):

..are you looking for this?

http://jsfiddle.net/kpppvjmq/2/

all I needed to add is a

```
left:0;
```

..in the slide up element.